# Does Haskell re-evaluate a value when recalling a function depending on this value?

Tags: haskell

Assume I have

```
f :: Int -> MyType
f i = ......

voxel :: MyType
voxel = f 2

function1 :: Double -> MyType -> MyOtherType
function1 x w = ......

function2 :: Double -> MyOtherType
function2 y = function1 y voxel
```

Now, assume I call `function2` twice, for example `function2 1.0` then `function2 2.0` (I am in the context of `OpenGL` and `MyOtherType` is a graphical element to be plotted, and the user can change `y` with the keyboard).

Then, at the second call of `function2`, does Haskell re-evaluate `voxel`?

If I had such a situation in, say for example the C language, I would put a `printf` in `voxel` to know the answer, but I can't do such a thing with a pure Haskell function (can I?).

Comment: No, since `voxel` itself is a "postponed" computation. Once evaluated, it will store the outcome in the voxel "node". Note that this is *not* stored at the `f` function level (also known as *momoization*), it is only because you reference the same *variable*.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem. That's good news.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem although that answers the specific question, would it be possible to write a more in-depth answer about this generally?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "momoization"? :p

Comment: @Jubobs: memoization of course... :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Haskell doesn't say what happens.

GHC does not re-evaluate `voxel`; generally, `let`- and `where`-bound values are evaluated at most once. (Though keep in mind that class-polymorphic values behave like functions, where choosing an instance is function application, and these function calls are not memoized, so apparently benign class-polymorphic bindings will probably lead to many reevaluations.)

You can put a "`printf`" with `Debug.Trace.trace`, but this should be used for educational and debugging purposes only.

```
import Debug.Trace
voxel = trace "evaluated voxel" $ f 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the "`printf`" trick. (note: "class-polymorphic bindings" is Chinese for me.)

Comment: Sorry I have another question. If `voxel :: Int -> MyType`, and ` function2` calls `voxel 1`, is there a re-evaluation at a second call of `function2`, if it still calls `voxel 1`, or is there no re-evaluation because there is a `voxel 1` "node", as says @WillemVanOnsem ?

Comment: Compiler optimizations _could_ result in `voxel 1` being evaluated once (ex. using `-O1` and a trivial test w/ `trace`)... but! There is no guarantee and in practice it will often be re-evaluated (I expect, checking how often would be an interesting exploration).

Comment: Ok @ThomasM.DuBuisson, thanks. I will try with `trace`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent If you want to be sure it is done only once, you can write it this way: `function2 = let expensive = voxel 1 in \arg -> {- do something with arg and expensive -}`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent "Class-polymorphic binding" means a value whose type has a class constraint. e.g. `x :: Num a => a; x = 0` is class-polymorphic and may be reevaluated at each use, while `id :: a -> a; id x = x` is polymorphic but not class-polymorphic and `x2 :: Int; x2 = 0` is monomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

It might, it might not, it depends on usage. Once it's evaluated, it'll stay evaluated until it gets garbage collected. As long as you have a reference to it somewhere, it can't be garbage collected.

Why would GHC allow a top level "constant" to be garbage collected? For a contrived example, imagine I have something like

```
nats :: [Integer]
nats = [0..]
```

and then another function which indexed into `nats`. If GHC couldn't collect `nats`, it'd have to store the list `[1..n]` (where `n` was the value that was indexed) even though I'm not using most of the list.